# Cannot resolve function getImageUrl() in glide dataset

Tags: android, android-studio, android-glide

This is my code I have included glide dataset in dependencies but I'm not able to access getImageUrl() and I'm getting cannot resolve function error, could someone help me out

```
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.banner_movie_layout, null);
        ImageView bannerImage= view.findViewById(R.id.banner_image);

      Glide.with(context).load(bannerMoviesList.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(bannerImage);
      container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }
```

This is my adapter class

```
public class BannerMoviePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<BannerMoviePagerAdapter> bannerMoviesList;

    public BannerMoviePagerAdapter(Context context, List<BannerMoviePagerAdapter> bannerMoviesList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.bannerMoviesList = bannerMoviesList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bannerMoviesList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view==object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.banner_movie_layout, null);
        ImageView bannerImage= view.findViewById(R.id.banner_image);

      Glide.with(context).load(bannerMoviesList.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(bannerImage);
      container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what is `bannerMoviesList` ?

Comment: Do you have getter and setter for the image url ?

Comment: bannerMovieslist is a lsit of adapter type that should hold the image urls

Comment: I'm not sure how to add the getter and setter

Comment: Please share where do you get bannerMoviesList. or share adpter class

Comment: I've updated question with adapter class

Comment: Your `BannerMoviePagerAdapter` can only be created with a List of other `BannerMoviePagerAdapter`s. That way you can never actually create an instance of it. Shouldn't it take a `List<BannerMovie>` or similar?

Comment: I've created list<BannerMovie> in main activity, it throws error in adapter class if I use anything other than List<BannerMoviePagerAdapter>

Comment: Investigate that error because it's likely part of your problem :)

Comment: the actual issue is that I'm not able to access getImageUrl() function from glide

Comment: Glide does not have a function `getImageUrl()`. You need the url of the data item you want to display. How to provide that is up to your application. Currently you try to get a url from a BannerMoviePagerAdapter, which doesn't have one as you noticed. It would make sense for a BannerMovie to have a url though and if so you need the list of banner movies available in the adapter.

Comment: thank you all, the issue got resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create A model class where you add setter and getter. Set data on that model class and pass that model class to adapter.

```
            ModelClass MC= new valdelmc();
            MC.setName(data);
            MC.setImage(data);
            arraylist.add(MC);
            adapter = new  Adapter(getContext(), arraylist);
```

In Adapter

```
 final List<ModelClass > modelFeedArrayList;
    public Adapter(Context context, final List<ModelClass> modelFeedArrayList ) {
        this.context = context;
        this.modelFeedArrayList = modelFeedArrayList;

    }
   ModelClass MC= modelFeedArrayList.get(position);
            Glide.with(context)
                .load(MC.getImage())
                .into(holder.img);
```

Demo Model Class

```
public class ModelClass{
 String  name,image;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```